# Can't find -lGL from /usr/lib/ld

Tags: compiling, c++, code-blocks

Whenever I try to compile Code::Blocks' C++ projects I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
```

I've tried installing following packages in accordance to other solutions to this problem:

```
fglrx-dev
fglrx-updates
fglrx-updates-dev
```

The 3 above couldn't be found.

```
mesa-common-dev
freeglut3-dev
freeglut3
libgl1-mesa-dev
build-essential checkinstall libc6-dev libssl-dev libexpat1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libqt4-dev libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev pkg-config
libxmu-dev
libxmu-headers
libxext-dev
libxi-dev
```

All of these were either already installed or didn't do anything.
I have nvidia-driver-515.

Comment: do you have Nvidia drivers installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused because the linker (`/user/bin/ld`) cannot find `libGL.so`. This library is provided by the `libgl1-mesa-dev` package, but it is possible that some symlinks got messed up.

1. You can try to reinstall `libgl1-mesa-dev` using

   ```
   sudo apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dev
   ```

   If the error is caused by a broken symlink, reinstalling can cause symlinks to be re-created, and therefore fixed.
2. You can try re-creating the symlink yourself. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` should be symlinked to wherever the actual `libGL.so` file (possibly with a suffix like `.1` or similar) is located. You can look under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or `/usr/lib` for the file, remove the symlink currently at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` and then re-create the symlink to the actual library using

   ```
   sudo ln -s /path/to/libGL.so(.1) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
   ```

Comment: From /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so I found libGL.so.1-file, with an arrow on icon, next to libGL.so.1.7.0. I removed libGL.so.1 and did the command line, brackets removed. But I got a libGL.so file with an x-mark on icon, and the projects still won't compile.

Comment: if the file you have is `ligbGL.so.1.7.0`, then do `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`.

Comment: `/path/to/libGL.so(.1)` was only a placeholder for whichever actual libGL you have. And you probably should not have deleted the symlink at `libgl.so.1`, possibly something else uses that. You can re-create it using `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`

Comment: Okay it worked. Thanks!